# Execute shell using arguments file from git

Tags: ansible

I've managed to set up a minimal Ansible playbook to execute some scripts on my machines:

```
- name: Execute CLI on remote servers
  hosts: webserver
  tasks:
    - name: Get metrics
      shell: /home/user1/bin/cli.sh --file=script.cli
```

The only issue is that this relies on the filesystem to store the scripts. I'd like to store my script in a repository (such as git) and pass a reference to it as argument to the shell.Something like:

```
shell: /home/user1/bin/cli.sh --file=ssh://git@github.com/mylogin/script.cli
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: Is it really an ansible question? Either you should teach `cli.sh` to accept git-uri as parameter, or deliver `script.cli` (e.g. with `git` module) to the host before calling `cli.sh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a very elegant solution, but you can use the Ansible git module (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/git_module.html) to first clone the repository that contains your scripts on your target machine(s) (`webserver`) and then reference those files from the `shell` module.

Comment: Thanks as a matter of fact I was looking at the Ansible git module right now to see some examples

Comment: Not sure why you see this as 'not very elegant'. I think use of the git module is the most ansible-way of pulling the repo. +1